# BeautifulSoup: extracting values

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am starting to introduce myself with BeautifulSoup, and I have these lines of code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
block = soup.find("div", {"class": "datepicker-filter"})
```

The first line block contains :

```
div class="datepicker-filter" rel="18.04.2020"
```

All I need is the value of `rel`: How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual - asking question leads to almost immediate answer:

```
print(soup.find("div", {"class": "datepicker-filter", "rel": True}).get("rel"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.get()` method to get the value of attributes, i.e.

```py
rel = block.get('rel')
```